# VB.NET using row partial match

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, row

when i write the word (size) in the first textbox

my dictionary applies this row from access database:

[image]

and write (large-big-huge) in the second textbox

but i'm trying to do the opposite as searching for (large) for example

and the program gives (size) in the second textbox

but i must write (large-big-huge) to apply the previous row

how can i use the partial match with the database which is marked by (-)?

code of the function:

```
    Function argetword(ByVal content As String) As String
    Try
        Using adp As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Words]", connectionString)
            Using tbl As New DataTable
                If adp.Fill(tbl) > 0 Then
                    For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
                        content = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, row.Item("values"), row.Item("idom"), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    Next
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Return content
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

code for translation button:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        TextBox2.Text = argetword(TextBox1.Text)
```

additional information:

edited code:

```
    Function argetword(ByVal content As String) As String
    Try
        Using adp As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT English FROM [Words] WHERE Arabic LIKE '%" & content & "%'", connectionString)
            Using tbl As New DataTable
                If adp.Fill(tbl) > 0 Then
                    For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
                        content = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, row.Item("Arabic"), row.Item("English"), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    Next
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Return content
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

a picture of database:

[image]

snapshot of the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are getting all the values, then going through each one to check if the one column matches the input -- This seems needlessly complicated for (what I think anyway) you are trying to do.

Why not alter the select statement -

```
"SELECT values FROM Words WHERE idom = '" & content & "'"
```

Then the other way -

```
"SELECT idom FROM Words WHERE values LIKE '*" & content & "*'"
```

The "Like" keyword returns any value containing content, and the percentage symbols mean there can be anything before or after the word and it would still match

If you're set on doing it the way you have it now, you can use the string.Contains function to see if content is found in either columns.

```
If row.item("values").contains(content) orelse row.item("idom").contains(content)
```

etc

Comment: as you said i added the line: ("SELECT Idom FROM Words WHERE Values LIKE '%" & content & "%'") but the program pops up a message saying: (column 'Values' does not belong to table)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your data structure. I thought your columns were called value and idom, if that's not the case then just replace those words with whatever your column names are

Comment: already do that, this error is after that, i tried to change this phrase without any success, any suggestion????

Comment: Didn't see that it was microsoft access, I've changed the 'Like' query to use * instead of %, you should really tag this question as Access to avoid confusion.

Comment: That error you are getting is pretty specific, either you don't actually have a column named values or you are looking at a different table than you think. I really can't help you more than that unless you post the code you've tried and all the relevant information (like database structure) in an edit or something

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, the new code is posted above with my database picture and the error message

Comment: Oh OK that makes things a little more clear. With my code you don't need to compare the columns afterwards, so you should remove the whole 'For each' loop. You can just take the first result, or if you think there could be multiple matches then you'll have to come up with some idea how to determine which one is best.

That code is failing because you are only asking for 'English' to be returned now, so the datatable doesn't have the Arabic column. If you want both you need to say Select English, Arabic from [Words]

Comment: the select part is done, but the problem of (-) separator still found (the main problem in topic), tried to remove "for each" loop but the word "row" became undefined and the program can't be debuged.

Comment: Without the for loop, you can't just use row.... You need to use tbl.rows(0) for the first row returned. If you are getting large-big-huge and you only want one of the words, you can split it using string.split("-"). Sorry, but It's becoming clear that I won't be able to help you through this, due to understanding issues on both our parts. I Hope you are able to figure this out yourself